# DbUnit - JdbcSQLException: Function "*" not found

Tags: java, sql-server, user-defined-functions, dbunit

I have a user-defined function in MS SQL Server called from Java code that appears to be undefined when running integration tests in H2 database. You can find my code in [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46342946/1429387).

Test code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {H2Config.class})
@TestExecutionListeners({
        DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class
})
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
public class TableDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    private TableDao tableDao;

    @Test
    @DatabaseSetup("/datasets/import.xml")
    public void testMethod01() {
        tableDao.getRecordsByGroup();
        ...
```

Database schema is autogenerated by Hibernate. As you can see data for the test is populated by DbUnit using xml dataset. And this test fails because my function that exists in MS SQL server DB is undefined in H2 database.

Application log:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
    ...
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "SAFE_MOD" not found; SQL statement:
    select table10_.id, table10_.value, ... from Table1 table10_ where table10_.group1=dbo.safe_mod(?, ?);
    ...
```

How to import / create a function before DbUnit test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

H2 database doesn't support user-defined SQL functions. However, in this database, Java functions can be used as stored procedures as well.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class H2Function {
    public static int safeMod(Integer n, Integer divider) {
        if (divider == null) {
            divider = 5000;
        }

        return n % divider;
    }

}
```

Note, that only static Java methods are supported; both the class and the method must be public.

The Java function must be declared (registered in the database) by calling `CREATE ALIAS ... FOR` before it can be used:

```
CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS safe_mod DETERMINISTIC FOR "by.naxa.H2Function.safeMod";
```

This statement should be executed before any test so I decided to put it inside connection init SQL:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:my_db_name");
    dataSource.setUsername("sa");
    dataSource.setPassword("");   
    dataSource.setConnectionInitSqls(Collections.singleton(
        "CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS safe_mod DETERMINISTIC FOR \"by.naxa.H2Function.safeMod\";"));

    return dataSource;
}
```

Comment: how to handle - callableStmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.BigInt);   in java function safeMod? if stored procedure is registered out param?

Comment: @Bibhaw I don't know. Please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1):

Credit to naxa, this solution is based on theirs. This is to 'stub' the WORD_SIMILARITY from postgres,

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(
        locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
public class testServiceTests {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void someTest() {

    }
}
```

This should be in your application-test.properties

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/my_database;MODE=PostgreSQL;INIT=CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS WORD_SIMILARITY DETERMINISTIC FOR "com.example.H2Function.wordSimilarity";TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=0;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
hibernate.flushMode=FLUSH_AUTO
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.data=classpath:V1__base-schema.sql
```

Here is the H2 function to replace

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class H2Function {

    public static double wordSimilarity(String string, String word) {
        if ( word== null ) {

            return 0;
        }

        return 0.5;
    }

}
```

Comment: how would you handle - callableStmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.BigInt); in your java method wordSimilarity? if the stored procedure is registered out-param

Answer (score 1):

@naXa and @Alan approaches works for scalar valued functions. For Table valued functions use `ResultSet`:

```
package com.package.app;
import org.h2.tools.SimpleResultSet;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class H2Functions {

    // All function params goes here
    // LocalDate not working here, we have to use java.sql.Date
    public static ResultSet gePrice(Long recipientId, Long currencyId, Date priceDate) {

        SimpleResultSet rs = new SimpleResultSet();
        rs.addColumn("price", Types.DECIMAL, 10, 0);
        rs.addColumn("priceDate", Types.TIMESTAMP, 10, 0);

        rs.addRow(new BigDecimal("123.23"), new Timestamp(LocalDateTime.now().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)) );

        return rs;
    }
}
```

Example application.yml configuration:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:h2:DB_NAME;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    name:
    username:
    password:
    hikari:
      auto-commit: false
      # create alias for functions on db connection initialization
      connection-init-sql: "CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS SAFE_MOD DETERMINISTIC FOR \"com.package.app.H2Functions.gePrice\";"
```

Then you can wrap response with your POJO.

More about user defined functions you can find in H2 documentation:
http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions

Comment: instead of `SAFE_MOD` use your own function name. e.g. `GET_PRICE`.